# Add ButtonDownload in cell of table in swift

Tags: ios, button, download, cell, addition

I want add DownloadButton to cell of table to do download. I added button success button call delegate. So,  Call delegate how?
This is library https://github.com/PavelKatunin/DownloadButton
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWWW6.png)

This is code in cell.

```
class DownloadCell: UITableViewCell, PKDownloadButtonDelegate , PKDownloaderSimulatorDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var lblLanguages: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imgDownloaded: UIImageView!

var downloaderSimulator: PKDownloaderSimulator?
var pendingSimulator : PKDownloaderSimulator?





override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

  startDownloadLanguage.delegate = self
    self.downloaderSimulator = PKDownloaderSimulator.init(progressInterval: 0.1)
    self.downloaderSimulator?.delegate = self;
    self.pendingSimulator = PKDownloaderSimulator.init(progressInterval: 0.05)
    self.pendingSimulator?.delegate = self;

}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)


}



@IBOutlet var startDownloadLanguage: PKDownloadButton!



func downloadButtonTapped(_ downloadButton: PKDownloadButton!, currentState state: PKDownloadButtonState) {
    //       
}


func simulator(_ simulator: PKDownloaderSimulator!, didUpdateProgress progress: Double) {

}
```

}

Comment: what you want to download on the click of button and what is the issue is occurring?

Comment: DemoDownload[47507:644454] -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800000d2c0
2017-08-20 18:35:02.341 DemoDownload[47507:644454] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSingleObjectArrayI setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800000d2c0'